# PHP cURL error 500

Tags: php, curl

I have been trying to get data from this [web page](http://www.mytransport.sg/content/mytransport/home/myconcierge/trafficcameras.html). I found that I need to pass the camera id [to this url](http://www.mytransport.sg/content/mytransport/home/myconcierge/trafficcameras/jcr%3acontent/par/cameras_slideshow.singleresult.html) using GET method to get image.

But every time I do a curl request I got http_code 500: internal server error

This is my code (I'm still trying out with static camera id):

```
$curl = curl_init('http://www.mytransport.sg/content/mytransport/home/myconcierge/trafficcameras/jcr:content/par/cameras_slideshow.singleresult.html?cameraid=4701');

curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.28 Safari/537.36");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.mytransport.sg/content/mytransport/home/myconcierge/trafficcameras.html");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true);

$resp = curl_exec($curl);
echo $resp;
$header = curl_getinfo($curl);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($header);
echo "</pre>";

curl_close($curl);
```

Result I get:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Date: Mon, 09 Sep 2013 15:26:56 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/5.0
Last-Modified: Thu, 04 Oct 2012 15:55:23 GMT
ETag: "7d2c5-402e-4cb3dc86ef0c0"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 16430
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Cache-Control: must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, private, must-revaildate, proxy-revalidate, private Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
```

Comment: What happens if you put the same request in a browser?

Comment: The URL itself works for me in a browser.  Now I didn't try to spoof the user agent and referer information so perhaps that is problematic on the server.

Comment: @AleksG Yes. It works in browser. I tried the curl request without all curlopt above and the output is the same

Comment: In a case like this, since you don't have any control over the sending server, I'd suggest contacting them to find out what else you might need to spoof or send to the server that the script is looking for. wget also gives 500, so it's not your script.